# problem while removing package from ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove libpixman-1-0 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatk-wrapper-java : Depends: default-jre but it is not going to be installed or
                                java2-runtime
                       Recommends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicated [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](http://askubuntu.com/q/124845)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove libpixman-1-0
```