# Error installing Steam on 14.04.03 (missing 32-bit libraries)

Tags: 14.04, apt, steam, shared-library

I have the Steam Launcher installed (installed via Software Center), when double-clicking the launcher the following is executed in the command window:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Press return to continue:
```

Upon pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the following dialogue box pops up:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1
```

What to do?

Comment: Whats the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` ?

Comment: >amd64
and
>i386
respectively

Comment: If it helps: This original post was about the error telling me I needed 'lib.so.6' 32-bit libraries, but I found some help someone had gotten previously, followed the advice, and this is the new response

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the full command with the output..

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not a command that results in the prompt about missing 'libGL.so.1', it is the Steam launcher that was installed via Software Center.  I will copy and paste the entire output after double-clicking on the steam launcher:

Comment: heemayl, thanks for looking at this - I have edited the original question to contain a little more context.  Sorry for not providing it before.

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/124845/216503) helps..

Comment: I checked the link and ran the following:
>sudo gedit /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log

Comment: which resulted in an empty log file.  I then ran the update and install commands to make sure everything was up to snuff.  The result was that no files were modified (I'm assuming that means my system was good to go)

Should I try to install the missing dependencies?  I'm unsure how to do that unless I just search their name in software center, or type something easy to interpret such as "sudo apt-get install <dependency name>".  I'm a bit of a rookie.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa:i386 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7`

Comment: Holy cow, it's like pandora's box:
>The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.2) but it is not going to be installed

                   Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed

                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : 
Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed

              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I'm going to try manually installing the new dependencies real quick (using the same syntax you posted above)

Comment: Yeah..go ahead..

Comment: Bizarre - those new "missing" dependencies are already there and up to date:

sudo apt-get install libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 gstreamer1.0-clutter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gstreamer1.0-clutter is already the newest version.
libclutter-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
libclutter-gst-2.0-0 is already the newest version.
libcogl15 is already the newest version.
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Also, sorry about the awful formatting...

Comment: Thats because it needs specific versions of the dependencies..try with versions mentioned e.g. for `libclutter-gst-2.0-0` use `sudo apt-get install libclutter-gst-2.0-0=0.10.0`

Comment: You will get some idea of what i have told from [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/216503)

Comment: That is an awesome link, thanks for that.  As for the specific versions, they were unfound:

E: Version '1.13.2' for 'libclutter-1.0-0' was not found
E: Version '0.91.8' for 'libclutter-gtk-1.0-0' was not found
E: Version '1.15.8' for 'libcogl15' was not found
E: Version '0.10.0' for 'libclutter-gst-2.0-0' was not found

Comment: I'm going to try using the '-f install' option to install the first dependencies you recommended I install

Comment: No dice.  Question:  When seeing "Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.2)" does that mean my current version is 1.13.2 and all that is necessary for the dependency is 1.0-0 or greater?  Vise versa?

Comment: `libclutter-1.0-0` is the package name and `1.13.2` is the version..run `apt-cache policy libclutter-1.0-0` you will get the idea..

Comment: That's bizarre, if they require a version >=1.13.2 then what I have installed (1.16.4) should meet that requirement.  Very odd, I'll keep poking around and see if there is a common fix.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26822/discussion-on-question-by-johnnyboy-error-installing-steam-on-14-04-03-missing).