# Unable to remove 'Unmet dependencies' in ubuntu precise

Tags: 12.04, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I am neither able to install nor remove any package through apt or dpkg. I don't have aptitude installed.
Here are unmet dependecies on my ubuntu version - 12.04 precise:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is installed
     libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is installed

     libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is installed
     libusb-1.0-0 : Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable

dpkg --purge libc-dev-bin
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libc-dev-bin:
     libc6-dev depends on libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12); however:
      Package libc-dev-bin is to be removed.
    dpkg: error processing libc-dev-bin (--purge):
     dependency problems - not removing

dpkg --purge libc6-dev
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libc6-dev:
     zlib1g-dev depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
      Package libc6-dev is to be removed.
      Package libc-dev is not installed.
      Package libc6-dev which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
     comerr-dev depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
      Package libc6-dev is to be removed.
      Package libc-dev is not installed.
      Package libc6-dev which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
     build-essential depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
      Package libc6-dev is to be removed.
      Package libc-dev is not installed.
      Package libc6-dev which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
     wireless-bcm43142-precise-dkms depends on libc6-dev.
     libstdc++6-4.6-dev depends on libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6).
     libexpat1-dev depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
      Package libc6-dev is to be removed.
      Package libc-dev is not installed.
      Package libc6-dev which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
     libtool depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
      Package libc6-dev is to be removed.
          Package libc-dev is not installed.
          Package libc6-dev which provides libc-dev is to.............


dpkg -s libc6-dev
        Package: libc6-dev
        Status: purge ok installed
        Multi-Arch: same
        Priority: optional
        Section: libdevel
        Installed-Size: 11595
        Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
        Architecture: amd64
        Source: eglibc
        Version: 2.15-0ubuntu10.12
        Provides: libc-dev
        Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12), libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12), linux-libc-dev
        Recommends: gcc | c-compiler
        Suggests: glibc-doc, manpages-dev
        Breaks: binutils (<< 2.20.1-1), binutils-gold (<< 2.20.1-11), cmake (<< 2.8.4+dfsg.1-5), gcc-4.4 (<< 4.4.6-3ubuntu1), gcc-4.4-base (<< 4.4.6-3ubuntu1), gcc-4.5 (<< 4.5.3-1ubuntu2), gcc-4.5-base (<< 4.5.3-1ubuntu2), gcc-4.6 (<< 4.6.0-12), gcj-4.4-base (<< 4.4.6-2ubuntu2), gcj-4.5-base (<< 4.5.3-1ubuntu2), gnat-4.4-base (<< 4.4.6-1ubuntu3), libhwloc-dev (<< 1.2-3), libjna-java (<< 3.2.7-4), liblouis-dev (<< 2.3.0-2), liblouisxml-dev (<< 2.4.0-2), make (<< 3.81-8.1), pkg-config (<< 0.26-1)
```

It seems that my current required packages have somehow become dependent on old version of libc6-dev (2.15-0ubuntu10.12).
How can I fix this?
I have tried to follow some other related threads but have failed to fix it so far.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Does `apt-get install -f` help?

Comment: No, It doesn't. I get this error-`E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies`

Comment: Hmm. You could try getting the `aptitude` DEB and doing a force install, then using it, but that could be dangerous.

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a` didn't made any difference. Is aptitude smarter than apt-get or dpkg?

Comment: `aptitude` is more aggressive than `apt-get`, which lets it fix more things (and break more things :p). Since it seems something got messed up, I would recommend trying it, but only after performing a backup. It might also be a good idea to go to 14.04, unless something is preventing that.

Comment: I have installed aptitude now by manually downloading deb files. It shows 5 broken packages. what command should I run to fix or purge them?

Comment: Try ` aptitude install -f`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue through Aptitude. It is cool and seems lot more powerful. It automatically downgraded some packages, removed a lot of them and installed few and fixed the dependencies.
Thanks to Zacharee1 for providing this tip.
I would highly recommend aptitude to manage packages especially when dpkg or apt-get fail.