# pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dependencies, 15.10

When I try to install something I received an error of dependencies and a incorrect gcc-5-base version installed.

When I put sudo apt-get install anyprogram:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 ddd : Depends: libxm4 (>= 2.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
 g++-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libasan2 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-21 is to be installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libgcc-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libmpx0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I put sudo apt-get -f install:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 g++-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libasan2 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-21 is  
installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libgcc-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libmpx0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I tried to use sudo apt-get update (it works, but the problem persist), and sudo apt-get upgrade, but with this I have the same error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 g++-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libasan2 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-21 is  
installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libgcc-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libmpx0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) but 5.3.1-5 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and fixed it. The problem occurred after I manually installed an incorrect `gcc` version with `dpkg`.

First, you need to know which package caused the dependent problem.
Use `dpkg -l | grep gcc` to find the wrong gcc package from the different package version.
`gcc-5-base` is the incorrect version package for me.

Then I try to reinstall the `gcc-5-base` package,
use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-5-base`. But error occurs after this command. Error likes:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/DEB PAKCAGENAME (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/"DIR NAME"/"FILE NAME"', which is different from other instances of package PAKCAGENAME
```

Rename the directory name and the error would fixed. Please refer to [apt-get error: trying to overwrite shared 'filename', which is different from other instances of package 'package'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124290/apt-get-error-trying-to-overwrite-shared-filename-which-is-different-from-ot)

Now, use`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-5-base` to got the previous version of gcc-5-base.

I hope it works for you.