# Software installation halted due to unmet dependencies (Tried remedy)

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies

I am trying to install a software package through the ubuntu software centre but I am getting this error:-

*The following packages have unmet dependencies:*

*gnome-control-center: Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: gnome-control-center-data (>= 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1) but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 is to be installed*

*unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed*

I have tried following the steps on [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) but I can't seem to upgrade/fix this one particular package named 'libgbm1' . I can't even remove it and the output goes:-

*The following packages have unmet dependencies:*

*indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed*

*libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
 libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 : Depends: libmirserver18 (>= 0.1.8+14.04.20140408.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libunity-mir1 : Depends: libmirserver18 (>= 0.1.8+14.04.20140411) but it is not going to be installed*

*E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.*

I am still a new ubuntu user and didn't really wish to go un-installing the control centres without knowing the repercussion. Does anyone know what I should do from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `aptitude`?

Try this-

```
sudo aptitude install <package_name>
```

It will repeatedly try to produce solutions, such as:

1. Keeping the same packages
2. Upgrading the packages
3. Downgrading the packages

Just keep hitting Y/N at the terminal. In most cases, it works out beautifully.

Comment: Don't i know it :)

Comment: Please copy/paste this answer as a solution to [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/124845/) and reply to this comment so that I can upvote it.