# 16.04 Unable to Correct Dependencies

Tags: 16.04, apt, dependencies

So I did something I was not supposed to by executing a command from the terminal (was having problems installing programs), and messed up the system. Can't install any programs and the upgrade command(among many others) won't work either. Software center and Libreoffice Calc have disappeared.

My problems had started after trying to install Java and OpenJDK. But they're trivial at this point i guess.

This is the output of the **sudo apt-get install -f** command:

http://pastebin.com/mhD7pSv4

This is the output of the **sudo apt-get update** command:

http://pastebin.com/gbvFBs6c

Is it practically possible to rescue the system from here ? Everything that is installed so far is working fine (firefox, wine etc.). I've tried *a lot* of things to no avail.

Comment: I was going to say that you should identify and remove the broken packages, but those are a lot of packages to remove. The "[solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)" directs you to look into the `/var/log/apt/term.log` and remove them with `sudo apt-get remove <package>`.

Comment: Hi Tony,

Thanks for your answer. Could you please have a look [here](http://pastebin.com/wB7JJC4P) and let me know which package I can attempt to remove for example ? I'm not sure the 
    sudo apt-get remove <package> command works without errors. Also, could you please have a look at entries in 2016-09-18 and let me know how much I have messed up or whether it's recoverable or not ?

Comment: Like Al said, you should probably backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu. The list is really long, 'cause that's a log of everything you have done for +2months. Your list is quiet long, and I also checked mine, definitely not a fun read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

Never run commands from the terminal prompt unless you're 100% sure what they do, before running them. You didn't say what your ran, but it really doesn't matter at this point, because you have too many problems. I'd recommend that you backup any important data, and just reinstall Ubuntu. If you do it right, it'll keep your existing home directory... but backup just in case something goes wrong. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hİ Al, thanks for your answer. You're right. I was having problems with chrome as well for 2 months now (NSS error). I was already having problems installing/removing programs, and it looked like I was going to have to do a reinstall at some point. So I figured what the hell and ran the commands anyway. The worst part is I had a ton of customizations and I'm going to have to do them from scratch which takes a lot of time. Welp. Anyway, could you please have a look [here](http://pastebin.com/wB7JJC4P) and let me know how much I messed up the system on 2016-09-18 ?

Comment: What were you trying to do on 2016-09-18? Whatever it was, it looks messed up. Just backup your important files and reinstall. If you tell Ubuntu to reinstall into the same partition as it already is, it should keep your existing /home directory... but backup just in case something goes wrong. Please vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Cheers, Al