# The following packages have unmet dependencies: skype

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
>  failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not installed
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
              Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libpulse0:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installed
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I could not install skype, also could not delete.

```
vegan@vegan:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not installed
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
              Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libpulse0:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installed
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

my ubuntu s 16.04
skype is skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb

Comment: Have you tried manually installing the dependencies?

Comment: PLease edit your question to include the release of Ubuntu that your are running (12.04/14.04/16.04/16.10) and the source for your skype package.

Comment: @Soupy i dont know how to do it. @ user535733 i added version .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the uninstallable dependencies, use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoremove`, as mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/831434/550148). Take a look at the other posts for that question too.

To actually install Skype, follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype) for installing through the official repositories, not through a separate `.deb` file.

---

Alternatively, this could be fixed by manually installing the dependencies using

`apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386`

with all the dependencies listed after `apt-get`, but as automatic installation is possible, I recommend not doing this.

Comment: i got error ` sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
[sudo] password for vegan: 
= 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be ins< 4:4lugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no package
`