# Upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, hard problem

Tags: apt, upgrade

I tried to update my laptop to ubuntu 17.10 without success.
Now it doesn't log in and many commands don't work anymore.
I'm an ubuntu user since many years and I never encountered such a big problem so far. All other questions on web don't really help me. There are some unmet dependencies that I cannot solve with `apt-get -f install` or `dpkg --configure -a` (or --audit) and/or update/upgrade/dist-upgrade.

The system replies that **pkgProblemResolver has some issues**, when I try with `apt-get -f install`. What do you suggest to do?
I don't want to reinstall the operating system (I have also a grub boot loader that works fine, with Windows 10 alongside my ubuntu).

Comment: Please provide the command and errors as shown in a terminal, and put those into the question. Regarding pkgProblemSolver also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel

Comment: Thanks, I added the image (sorry for the language of the terminal, I could change it in case). I've already seen the question, unfortunately it doesn't here.