# Unable to install libapache2-mod-php5 5.3+ on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, apache2, dpkg, dependencies, php

For some need I have to install php5.3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. I have installed PHP 5.3 from `ppp:ondraj/php5`. I have installed Apache 2.2. But while running `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` it is showing:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                            debconf-2.0
 fontconfig : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1)
              Depends: fontconfig-config but it is not going to be installed
 irqbalance : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       debconf-2.0
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-mpm-prefork (> 2.0.52) but it is not going to be installed or
                                apache2-mpm-itk but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ucf but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
 libblkid1 : Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libfontconfig1 : Depends: fontconfig-config (= 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5svg5 : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~)
              Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libsasl2-modules:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libsm6 : Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libsm6:i386 : Depends: libuuid1:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libssl1.0.0 : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                        debconf-2.0
 libssl1.1 : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                      debconf-2.0
 linux-sound-base : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                             debconf-2.0
 locales : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                    debconf-2.0
 memtest86+ : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       debconf-2.0
 monodoc-http : Depends: mono-xsp4 but it is not going to be installed or
                         mono-apache-server4 but it is not going to be installed or
                         mono-fastcgi-server4 but it is not going to be installed
 tzdata : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                   debconf-2.0
 wamerican : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                      debconf-2.0
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried `ppa-purge ppa:ondraj/php5` but the problem is same.

I tried to install from .deb source. Here is the output:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php5.
(Reading database ... 301538 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-php5_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php5 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.25) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php5:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2-api-20120211; however:
  Package apache2-api-20120211 is not installed.
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2 (>= 2.4); however:
  Version of apache2 on system is 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.11.
  Version of apache2 on system, provided by apache2-mpm-prefork:amd64, is <none>.
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.25); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26.
 dpkg (1.18.4ubuntu1.4) breaks libapache2-mod-php5 (<< 5.6.4+dfsg-3~) and is installed.
  Version of libapache2-mod-php5 to be configured is 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.25.
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Is there any way I can solve the problem? I really need to use PHP 5.3.

Comment: I'm having the same issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121552/unable-to-install-libapache2-mod-php5-6-on-ubuntu-xenial-16-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)