# dist-upgrade failed because pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages

Tags: package-management

I have the following packages have been kept back

```
    apparmor apport apport-gtk appstream apt apt-utils avahi-daemon avahi-utils bind9-host binutils bluez bluez-obexd brltty cpp cups cups-bsd
  cups-client cups-core-drivers cups-daemon curl debhelper dirmngr dnsutils dpkg dpkg-dev evince evince-common evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common file firefox fwupd g++ gcc gettext gfortran ghostscript ghostscript-x gir1.2-goa-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-vte-2.91
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 git git-man gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-keyring gnome-mines
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-shell-common
  gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnupg gpgv gstreamer1.0-alsa
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
  guile-2.0-libs gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-libs imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core
  libapparmor-perl libapt-pkg5.0 libarchive13 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libblkid1 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
  libcurl3-gnutls libdpkg-perl libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-28 libegl1-mesa
  libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libexiv2-14 libfdisk1 libgbm1 libgcrypt20 libgd3 libgettextpo-dev libgettextpo0 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgpgme11 libgs9 libgs9-common
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libkpathsea6 libldap-2.4-2
  libmagic1 libmount1 libnm-util2 libnm0 libpam-systemd libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
  libparted-fs-resize0 libparted2 libperl-dev libplymouth4 libpoppler-glib8 libptexenc1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp
  libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-stdlib libsmartcols1 libsmbclient libsnapd-glib1
  libsnmp-dev libsnmp30 libsoup2.4-1 libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libsynctex1 libsystemd0 libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 libudev-dev libudev1 libuuid1
  libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common libwayland-egl1-mesa libwbclient0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libxatracker2 libxml2 linux-tools-4.15.0-42-generic
  linux-tools-4.15.0-43-generic linux-tools-oem lshw man-db mesa-vdpau-drivers mount openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server parted
  perl perl-base plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text poppler-utils ppp procps pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-brlapi
  python3-cryptography python3-gdbm python3-louis python3-lxml python3-minimal python3-requests python3-software-properties samba-libs
  shotwell shotwell-common software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ssh systemd systemd-sysv texlive-binaries ubuntu-session
  ubuntu-software udev util-linux uuid-runtime
```

I tried  `sudo apt-get install <list of packages kept back>`  but I got the following

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OsAlR1wBtlnZ_F-eweU0gdyV-aIZW5vM

finally, I tried an aggressive solution by using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but I got the same previous error.

how to fix this problem? i.e

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

my system is ubuntu 16.04

```
uname -a
4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 7 13:31:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

my source.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

Comment: You haven't told us your version of Ubuntu, but it looks like you have mixed sources (including xenial, bionic  or various version of Ubuntu, possibly non-Ubuntu sources too). I'd suggest providing a link to your sources.list, and are you even using Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @guiverc how to provide a list to my sources.list

Comment: If running xenial (16.04), the correct `libgtk-3-0` is 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 which is what is provided, not what is required by something non-xenial on your sources.  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgtk-3-0&searchon=names)  Your sources are your problem; they are `/etc/apt/sources.list` (which doesn't include PPA's but it's a good start)

Comment: @guiverc ok, I updated the post with my sources.list, could you see it please?

Comment: You have "bionic-updates" in your sources; so your system contains 18.04 updated packages; which is what is needing requiring non-xenial packages. I don't know when you added it, but you've now got a mixture of 18.04 packages in your 16.04 system creating the problem. I'd suggest backing those packages out.. which is a rather messy job (unless it was very recent).  You've trimmed comments, hopefully whoever made that change left comments (inc. date/reason) as to why it was added; or using apt's logs would be my next place to look.  Restoring backups may be easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)