# python-samba not installable during `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates, samba

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba-common-bin : Depends: python-samba but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

How to resolve this problem? I tried `sudo apt-get install -y python-samba` but it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-samba' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)