# pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks

Tags: apt, upgrade

I tried to upgrade my system via do-release-upgrade but some error occured. Now whatever I do (upgrade, dist-uprade, dpkg --configure -a, etc), I get many errors. For example:

```
root@hcompneu:~# apt-get dist-upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 glib-networking : Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.6) but 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.9 is installed
                   Depends: libproxy1v5 (>= 0.4.14) but 0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2 is installed
 glib-networking-services : Depends: libproxy1v5 (>= 0.4.14) but 0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2 is installed
 ibus : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
 indicator-keyboard : Depends: libfcitx-gclient1 (>= 1:4.2.9.5) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-17 (>= 3.17.92) but it is not installed
                      Depends: indicator-common but it is not installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev-bin (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9)
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libboost-locale1.65.1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libclucene-contribs1v5 (>= 2.3.3.4+dfsg) but 2.3.3.4-4.1 is installed
                    Depends: libclucene-core1v5 (>= 2.3.3.4+dfsg) but 2.3.3.4-4.1 is installed
                    Depends: libcmis-0.5-5v5 (>= 0.5.1+git20160603) but 0.5.1-2ubuntu2 is installed
                    Depends: libgpgmepp6 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libhunspell-1.6-0 but it is not installed
                    Depends: liborcus-0.13-0 (>= 0.13.3) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libpoppler73 (>= 0.62.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libxmlsec1 (>= 1.2.25) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libxmlsec1-nss (>= 1.2.25) but it is not installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.31) but 237-3ubuntu10.52 is installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libfcitx-gclient1 (>= 1:4.2.9.5) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-17 (>= 3.27.90) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libgtop-2.0-11 (>= 2.22.3) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libunity-control-center1 (>= 15.04.0+17.10.20171225) but 15.04.0+16.04.20171130
-0ubuntu1 is installed
                        Recommends: system-config-printer but it is not installed
                        Recommends: gnome-control-center-faces but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I have no idea how to resolve this. I tried many of the commands found here on Askubuntu for similar errors but none of them work.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

apt-mark showhold gives nothing.

I tried also apt, apt-get, aptitude, synaptics. All behave somewhat different but end up in errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Comment: You have to try Aptitude. Install it with `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and then run `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` .