# how do I resolve an error that occurs when installing wine-stable where wine32 is missing in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wine, 22.04

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libldap-2.5-0 : Depends: libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2) but it is not installable
 libpulse0 : Depends: libapparmor1 (>= 2.7.0~beta1+bzr1772) but it is not installable
 libsane1 : Depends: libsnmp40 (>= 5.9.1+dfsg) but it is not installable
            Recommends: ipp-usb but it is not going to be installed
 libxml2 : Depends: libicu70 (>= 70.1-1~) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141655/discussion-on-question-by-victor-creations-how-do-i-resolve-an-error-that-occurs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)