# Cant install wine32 on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: wine, 23.04

Im trying to install Wine on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 23.04 but im having trouble with wine32.

*$ sudo apt install wine*

The regular continue question says that wine 32 is a recommended package. Installation completes with no warnings.

*$ wine*

Gives response:
*it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it. as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32:i386" Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
wine --help                   Display this help and exit
wine --version                Output version information and exit"*

*sudo apt install wine32*

Gives response:
*Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.*

*$ sudo apt install wine'tab-tab'*

wine32 doesnt show up in the list.

*$apt search --names-only wine32*

wine32 is found in the repository.

I have already enabled i386 and also tried to fallow the installation instructions on wineHQ webpage with no better luck.

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to do exactly what the error message said? "... as root, please execute `apt-get install wine32:i386`"

Comment: Yes i did and got the same result as "$ sudo apt install wine32" gave.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (couldn't install wine32 on Ubuntu 23.10). For me worked simply

```
sudo apt update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

worked.

After that when running wine I got the following error:

> wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135

which I fixed according to https://forum.manjaro.org/t/wine-could-not-load-kernel32-dll-status-c0000135/69811/2:

1. remove ~/.wine: `rm -r ~/.wine`
2. `winecfg`

Answer (score 0):

You tried installing something with wine already ?
use wine as normal user

```
wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]
```

and check if it works...