# Steam have unmet dependencies cant install steam

Tags: command-line, steam

````
[sudo] password for g: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.11) but it is not going to be installed
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)                                                                                                                                        
 util-linux : PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable                                                                                                                           
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. ```
````

I have tried most of answers in google still doesnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494732/edit) to show us the complete output of `apt policy libapt-pkg6.0` and of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that there are unmet dependencies, and resolving it might involve fixing the package management system. Here are steps you can take to address the issue:

**1. Update Package Lists:** Before making any changes, ensure your package lists are up to date.  Run: `sudo apt update`

**2. Fix Broken Packages:** Attempt to fix broken packages using:
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

**3. Fix Broken Packages:** Upgrade your installed packages to the latest versions:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

**4. Dist-Upgrade:** Upgrade your installed packages to the latest versions: `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

**5. Check for Held Packages:** Identify and deal with any held packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```

**6. Remove Problematic Packages:** If a specific package is causing issues, you might try removing it: `sudo apt remove <problematic-package>`

**7. Clean Package Cache:** Clear the local package cache to avoid potential conflicts:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

**8. Reconfigure dpkg:** Force dpkg to reconfigure packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**9. Check APT Configuration:** Ensure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is correctly configured. You may want to use a tool like `software-properties-gtk` to manage your software sources.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

**10. Check Systemd Configuration:** Ensure that the systemd package is properly installed. Run: `sudo apt install systemd`

These all should mostly resolve your issues. After Finishing these steps you could try again to install the Steam software. I would suggest following any official documentation or guide in doing so in order to correctly install the application.

Comment: The OP's output suggests a real version conflict or missing source that must be resolved. None of these steps will do that. Or, rather, the one useful step is not explained clearly enough to be useful.