# I am having problem when I am trying to remove python from my pc

Tags: package-management, python, dpkg, dependencies, grub-efi

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not installable or
                        base-files (< 12.3) but 13ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
               Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Python is needed for Ubuntu to work. If you remove it your computer will not work. You will have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. An error message is not a question.

Comment: What command produce the output shown in the post ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Comment: Why do you want to remove python? Do you want to install a different python version? Then use Anaconda instead. It will create an isolated virtual environment for any python version you want to use

Comment: Yeah, and you can always install and then run the other version explicitly, that is, by calling it by the exact python version instead of simply using the `python` command when you need it so that the needed python version on the system remains the same and there's no need to remove it.