# Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages, specific package can not be removed

Tags: apt, updates

Edited for more context.
The suggested links to fix the issue focus on removing the broken package. If I try to remove the `sysvinit-utils` package I get the output as indicated below (the long list of dependencies of `lsb-base`) and the remove fails. So the suggested link does not resolve it, I have tried the several additional options like removing the package with dpkg directly and the same happens. **So I'm stuck in a loop**.

[Suggested duplicate link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)
This link does not fix it, please look at the content of my request and you will see that this is a "simple" non-essential package that would need to be removed. It does not fix my issue, hence the reason I opened this request.

I wanted to update smartmontools to 7.4 in Ubuntu 22.04 (It is not for ubu22, version 7.4 is not available) so I installed the latest version using dpkg and then several dependencies were needed so I installed also the latest version of sysvinit-utils (3.08-6ubuntu2, again not for ubu22), then the dependency of libc6 and I do not want to do that due to additional dependencies. So in trying to revert the changes I run into the following issue:

Now when I want to run apt upgrade I get this:

```
sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for niels:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sysvinit-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I run it and get:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sysvinit-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I can't downgrade the sysvinit-utils to the previous version:

```
sudo apt install sysvinit-utils=3.01-1ubuntu1
[sudo] password for niels:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for niels:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 acpid : Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.2-14)
---snip---
 unattended-upgrades : Depends: lsb-base
 x11-common : Depends: lsb-base (>= 1.3-9ubuntu2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried to do what is suggested here and I keep getting back to the same issue:
[How to downgrade a package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Removed the partially installed `smartmontools` package, installed `lsb-base` package, then downloaded `sysvinit-utils_3.01-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`, installed it and back to normal.

I can update/upgrade.